# Plans for pluginlib for Python

Tags: ros, python, pluginlib, trajectory-filters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any way (or plan to make a way) to create plugins in Python? It seems C++ is the only option at the moment.

Specifically I'd like to make trajectory filters in Python.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11521/plans-for-pluginlib-for-python/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2011-10-12

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One of the best options to comply with the existing architecture is to write a plugin using python, then wrap it with [boost python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/python/doc/). I've used it a lot and it is extremely easy to wrap C++ code in Python and call the python interpreter (thus your plugin) from C++.

I usually write code in Python, profile it and write in C++ the functions that are more demanding. With boost one can easily have a C++ code (the plugin interface) that calls Python (your plugin) that calls some other C++ functions for time-critical applications!

---

Originally posted by [Lorenzo Riano](https://answers.ros.org/users/155/lorenzo-riano/) with karma: 1342 on 2011-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

"Plugins" in python are much simpler and don't need a special library to dynamically load a library.  If you'd like an example of a python plugin infrastructure inside ROS take a look at [roswtf](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roswtf)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-10-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2011-10-13**:
That's one way to do it, but roswtf doesn't use pluginlib. pluginlib (and the associated packages filters and trajectory_filters) uses a ClassLoader which loads up a specific C++ class in order to use the plugin.